# Create a .NET Application with MATLAB Code

Tags: .net, matlab, exception

I am trying to interface some data acquired from Matlab and a C# application. I am trying to transform a MATLAB function into a .NET assembly and integrate it into the .NET application.

I started with a very simple example proposed from the mathWorks documentation on this link(http://uk.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-cc-application-with-matlab-code-1.html) and I have followed all the steps presented. After having followed all the step  of the tutorial and added the reference to my assembly created through the Matlab library compiler and the reference to the MWArray API, when I debag the application, an exception is thrown when I am trying to create an instance of the class I have created with the Matlab library compiler.

The exception is the following:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in MainApp.exe"

I have installed the Matlab Runtime version 9.0 as required by the readme.txt and I am running the code on a 8.1 Windows 64bit on a MwareFusion (Virtual Machine) on Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the code and to the tutorial. I replicated the same steps also on my machine and I figured out the problem. Essentially, if you navigate through the inner exceptions, you can find that the constructor fails with exception error:

> Exception form HRESULT: 0x8007000B

This may be caused by the fact that Matlab creates the dll to be run at 64 bits, while, using the default configuration, Visual Studio compiles at 32 bits.

Therefore I suggest to change the target of you application in the menu Configuration Menager from Any CPU to x64. This should solve the problem.